# Split a cell into multiple rows based on line break and format data elements

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

The datasets are small (10-25 lines), but I have to run a lot of them and it's getting to be a waste of time.

The original data looks like this:
[image]

The output needs to look like this:
[image]

```vb
Sub x()

Dim v, vOut(), i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, w

v = Sheet8.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
ReDim vOut(1 To UBound(v, 1) * 10, 1 To 2)
For i = LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1)
    w = Split(v(i, 2), Chr(10))    
    For j = LBound(w) To UBound(w)
        k = k + 1
        vOut(k, 1) = v(i, 1)
        vOut(k, 2) = w(j)
    Next j
Next i

Sheet9.Range("A1").Resize(k, 2) = vOut

End Sub
```

I managed to separate the rows.

I'm lost on how to efficiently automate the rest of the formatting. I could do it through a bunch of Splits but feel there's probably a better way.

Comment: post what you tried to get help.  I do not think you will get someone to do this for you from scratch.

Comment: To detect line-breaks in a cell's contents you can do  `If Instr(Cells(i,j).Value, vbLf) <> 0`. Other than that, you can maybe use [Regex](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/regex/) to grab the values you need. If not regex, then a custom string parsing using `InStr`, `Split` and `Mid`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Messy, but eventually figured it out:

```
Sub VisitInfo()

Dim v, vOut(), i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, w, z

v = Sheet8.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
ReDim vOut(1 To UBound(v, 1) * 10, 1 To 4)
For i = LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1)
    w = Split(v(i, 2), Chr(10))
    
    
    For j = LBound(w) To UBound(w)
        k = k + 1
        vOut(k, 1) = v(i, 1)
        z = Split(w(j), "]")
        a = Split(w(j), "] ")
        c = Split(a(1), " o")
        b = Split(w(j), "=")
        vOut(k, 2) = (z(0) + "]")
        vOut(k, 3) = (c(0))
        vOut(k, 4) = LTrim(b(1))
        
    Next j
Next i

Sheet3.Range("A2").Resize(k, 4) = vOut

End Sub
```

Comment: woohoo, great perseverence hannah!